# RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #3 'index'

Tags: python, nlp

```
    LSTM(
      (embed): Embedding(139948, 12, padding_idx=0)
      (lstm): LSTM(12, 12, num_layers=2, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
      (lin): Linear(in_features=240, out_features=6, bias=True)
    )
    Train epoch : 1,  loss : 771.319284286499,  accuracy :0.590
    =================================================================================================
    Traceback (most recent call last):enter code here
      File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/example.py", line 297, in <module>
        scores = model(x_test, x_test_seq_length)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/example.py", line 141, in forward
        x = self.embed(x)  # sequence_length(max_len), batch_size, embed_size
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
        result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 117, in forward
        self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1506, in embedding
        return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
    RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #3 'index'
```

It works fine on the training set, but I keep getting that error in the test set. I've been thinking for 10 hours.

What is problem??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your program is expecting to run using the GPU but is instead being run on the CPU. Make sure you have your GPU settings for your program set correctly and the version of CUDA you're using is up-to-date.

You can find more information on this here (Assuming you're using tensorflow):
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Answer (score 0):

If you trained the model on your CPU, then the test data was loaded and converted to the CUDA datatype somehow. So, you can solve this issue by moving your input tensors to CPU device. And move the model as well (it won't hurt).

This can be done like so:

```
>>> import torch
>>> device = torch.device("cpu")
>>> # move the model
>>> model = model.to(device)
>>> # move any input tensors
>>> test_data = test_data.to(device)
```